# Access parent state controller from nested state in angularui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have defined nested states in my project:

```
        $stateProvider
    .state("MultiStepForm", {
        url: "/Sensor/MultiStepForm",
        templateUrl: "/app/MultiStepForm/MultiStepForm.html",
        controller: "MultiStepFormController",
        controllerAs: "MultiStepLogic"
    })
        .state('MultiStepForm.step1', {
            url: '/step1',
            templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/NestedViews/FormStep1.html',
            controller: "MultiStepLogicStep1Controller",
            controllerAs: "Step1"
        })
        .state('MultiStepForm.step2', {
            url: '/step2',
            templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/NestedViews/FormStep2.html',
            controller: "MultiStepLogicStep2Controller",
            controllerAs: "Step2"
    })
        .state('MultiStepForm.step3', {
            url: '/step3',
            templateUrl: '/app/MultiStepForm/NestedViews/FormStep3.html',
            controller: "MultiStepLogicStep3Controller",
            controllerAs: "Step3"
        });
```

In **MultiStepForm** state I have defined this property:

```
var self = this;
this.data = "someObject";
```

In **MultiStepForm.step3** state controller(Step3) I want to access property that defined in parent state controller:

this.data = "some data from MultiStepForm.step3 state"

My question is how can I access parent property from nested state controller?

Comment: I don't believe this is a dupe, as Angular v2 is moving towards isolated scope, so a $scope-based answer is probably not the right one. My answer below solves the problem without using $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to 'resolve' that data before injecting it into the controller. If it is resolved at the parent, it will be available to the children.

Like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("MultiStepForm", {
        url: "/Sensor/MultiStepForm",
        templateUrl: "/app/MultiStepForm/MultiStepForm.html",
        controller: "MultiStepFormController",
        controllerAs: "MultiStepLogic",
        resolve: {
          your_custom_data: ['$stateParams', 'another_service',
                function($stateParams, another_service) {
                    //you can use $stateParams or other services here as needed to get the data you want
                    return the_value_of_your_custom_data;
                }],
    })
```

Then in your controller:

```
angular
    .module('your_app')
    .controller('MultiStepLogicStep3Controller', MultiStepLogicStep3Controller);

function MultiStepLogicStep3Controller($state, your_custom_data) {
    //access your $state or custom data here
    this.custom_data = your_custom_data;
}
```

Comment: do I have to make injection dependency like that:
.controller('MultiStepLogicStep3Controller', ["your_custom_data",MultiStepLogicStep3Controller]);

Comment: nope, that's just how I format my controllers.

Comment: Yes it's helped me!Thanks!